# VB.Net: Byref-in a parent type but return child type to ByRef

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, inheritance, byref

how do I keep the child type returned to the ByRef referenced variable in this scenario?

```
Public Class Father
End Class

Public Class Son
   Inherits Father
End Class

' Should return a Son, not a Father
Public Sub Save(ByRef obj as Father)
```

Comment: This should be a Function instead.  Google "factory method pattern" to learn more.

Comment: A Son isn't always a Father, I hope mine isn't for a while... Can you juste change it to a function? Public Function Save(ByVal obj as Father) As Son

Answer (score 1):

But you could assign a `Son`, if you want:

```
' Should return a Son, not a Father
Public Sub Save(ByRef obj As Father)
    obj = New Son
End Sub
```

Now you have a `Son` instead of a `Father` when you call `Save`:

```
Dim father As New Father
Save(father)
If TypeOf father Is Son Then
    Console.Write("Yes, i'm a son") ' this is executed '
End If
```

You have to cast it to be able to use it as `Son`:

```
If TypeOf father Is Son Then
    Dim son = DirectCast(father, Son)
End If
```